# Weird double release with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a subclass of a view controller. After adding the view of this view controller to another view, any interaction with the view of `MyViewController` causes a crash. When running zombies it shows a double release, the retain count of `myViewController` has gone to -1.

I am calling `alloc` on this object, which should bring the retain count to 1, and I am also adding the view of `myViewcontroller` to another view, which should bring the retain count to 2. So how am I getting a double release? **This only crashes on ARC**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   MyViewcontroller *myViewcontroller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
   [self.view addSubview:myViewcontroller.view];
}
```

Comment: @RichardBrightwell I don't understand the question? what's wrong with [super viewDidLoad]?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with Load, but Laod... you don't want that in your cdoe. ;-)

Comment: ooo yeah my bad I wrote the code on here, and not in Xcode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no "double" release here, just the one.

You're storing the view controller in a local variable here. ARC correctly releases it when this method ends -- to do otherwise would cause a leak because you won't have a reference to it anymore.*

> I am also adding the view of `myViewcontroller` to another view, which should bring the retain count to 2.

No; `addSubview:` takes ownership of the *view*, not the *controller*. The view itself will still be alive later, but the controller won't.

---

*So, interestingly, this would not crash under MRR, but would be incorrect.

Comment: In MRR, I would release the object after a delegate call, So viewDidSelectDone would remove the view from superView and then release the viewController. Is this no longer possible with arc? I beleive NSUrlConnection uses the same pattern.

Comment: ARC just does automatically what you should have done; it doesn't change the rules. I'd have to see that code to know whether you're doing something wrong, but it sounds a little funny. Delegates don't usually own their delegators, and shouldn't usually release them.

Comment: Look the link below: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html connection:didFailWithError: OR connectionDidFinishLoading. This is a common pattern used in Cocoa, I've seen this in various places.

Comment: You're right, I had that backwards; `NSURLConnection` delegates _do_ (usually) own the connection.